# C# Creating a collection/list of parametized actions programmaticly

Tags: c#, list, collections, parallel-processing, action

I have an n number of objects of a class, for each of these objects something has to be done. This process must be performed parallel for all objects. These objects are in a list. Can I somehow create an action for each object in this list with that object as a parameter, and then put that action into another collection so that I can use that collection as an argument for this here.

```
Parallel.Invoke(myCollectionOfActions);
```

Maybe something like this:

```
List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();
foreach(Test test in Tests) //Tests is the my list
{
    actions.Add(new Action(MyMethod(test));
}

Parallel.Invoke(actions);
```

I don't know if that's even possible. It doesn't have to be a solution like this. As long as it works somehow. Thanks

Comment: Seems to me that what you 'need' is the Task parallel library. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl

Comment: Is `MyMethod` void? If so, you could call `Parallel.ForEach(Tests, (test) => MyMethod(test));`

Comment: Yes, ```Parallel.ForEach(Tests, (test) => MyMethod(test));``` works fine. Thanks :)